# Push elements off screen when resizing window instead of squishing them

Tags: html, css, position, display

I would like to push my elements off the screen when making the window smaller, instead of squishing them together. Very similar to the top section of this page (the top image with the text) - http://www.kirastokes.com/schedule/ . If you make the window smaller part of the image moves off the screen so you can see the text box. Instead of squishing everything together, the elements on the page just sort of shift off. How would I do this?

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhe9jtqw/

```css
#top-section-intro-container
{
    height:700px;
    position:relative;
}

#top-section-intro-image
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
        width: 892px;
    height: 650px;
}
#top-section-intro-text-container
{

        z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:black;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;

    background-color:white;
    width: 558px;
    height: 480px;
    left: 800px;
    top: 78px;
}
.top-section-intro-text {
  left: 0px;
    padding-top: 144px;
    padding-left:95px;
    width: 530px;
    height: 285px;
    font-size:18px;
   font-family: lato;
    font-style: normal;
 text-align:justify;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.1px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #255957;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-section-intro-container">
    <img id="top-section-intro-image" src="https://www.outsideonline.com/sites/default/files/styles/full-page/public/2018/05/01/alaska-trees-forest-fog-richard-bos_h.jpg?itok=eOaGR4uY"/>
    <div id="top-section-intro-text-container">
    <p class="top-section-intro-text">
        
A forest is a large area dominated by trees.[1] Hundreds of more precise definitions of forest are used throughout the world, incorporating factors such as tree density, tree height, land use, legal standing and ecological function.[2][3][4] According to the widely used[5][6] Food and Agriculture Organization definition, forests covered 4 billion hectares (9.9×109 acres) (15 million square miles) or approximately 30 percent of the world's land area in 2006. 
</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that this way.
If for example min width of your site (when it still looks good) ~ 1000px then:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        var x, temp = window.innerWidth;
        if((x = 1000 - temp) > 0){
            $("#top-section-intro-container").css({left:  -x});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using css media queries for that purpose.

So let's say you want to keep the page responsive until a specific width (e.g. 1000px), you can define a media query for it.

```
.myTopNav {
   display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   .myTopNav {
      display: initial;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
   }
}
```

So the class myTopNav will only be overwritten for a width of 1000px or less.

To learn more about it have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp